# Redirecting old URLs to new URLs based on tags

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

We had a database corruption on our website, now we are building a new one.

However, we have thought off a different approach, we are migrating our old articles to a sub domain and building a new website with a better UI and architecture.

What I would like to do is redirect url from old website to the sub domain, with out in the format as this:

```
http://olddomain.com/foo/something
```

to

```
http://sub.olddomain.com/foo/something
```

and we want to keep the the olddomain to serve new content

```
http://oldomain.com/foo2/something
```

is this possible with Nginx

---

UPDATE

We have a set word based on which we want to redirect

we just want

```
 http://olddomain/foo/extrainfo
```

to redirect

```
http://sub.olddomain/foo/extra
```

when using the rewrite rule

```
/abc/ redirect permanent
```

we are having an issues that is a URL has word **foo** it's getting redirected to the new domain.

we just want `http://olddomain/foo/` to redirect to http://sub.olddomain./foo/extra

not `http://olddomain/abc/foo` to `http://sub.olddomain`

Comment: is there determined words like `foo` to match when deciding if we redirect or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something within your URL to identify if it's an old URL or a new URL. If you have something, than it's easy and we can answer the question. Your given example could easily be solved with:

```
location ~ ^/[a-z]+/[a-z]+$ {
  return 302 $scheme://sub.$server_name$request_uri;
}

location ~ ^/[a-z0-9]+/[a-z]$ {
  // serve new stuff
}
```

But don't forget about search engines and other robots! If you plan to use the original URLs for the new content in the future don't redirect anything and simply deliver the pages at the same places.

Comment: Thanks for the information, we are actually shedding old data to a sub domain and keep it.
we are trying to not loose 18K links and would like them to be redirected to the new sub domain.

I will check this and get back

thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is simple with nginx. You just need to put a rewrite rule in the correct location/server blocks:

```
server { 
    listen       80;
    server_name olddomain.com;
location ~/foo/ {
 rewrite ^ http://sub.olddomain.com$request_uri? permanent;
    }
  location / {
#serve new content
    }
}

server{
        listen       80;
        server_name sub.olddomain.com;
      location / {
    #serve old content
        }
}
```

I would second the previous comment that you should make sure you take into account SEO.